# Properly close a Go routine which runs an infinite loop

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a go routine which is basically acting as a `KafkaConsumer`, it reads messages from a topic and then spawns another `go routine` for each message it receives. Now this `Consumer go routine` is supposed to be shutdown when the application which is the `main go routine` shuts down. But I am facing difficulties in properly shutting this down. 
Below is the `Kafka Consumer` definition

```
    package svc    

import (
    "event-service/pkg/pb"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto"
    "gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1/kafka"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"
)    

type EventConsumer func(event eventService.Event)    

type KafkaConsumer struct {
    done            chan bool
    eventChannels   []string
    consumer        *kafka.Consumer
    consumerMapping map[string]EventConsumer
    wg              *sync.WaitGroup
}    

func getKafkaConsumerConfigMap(config map[string]interface{}) *kafka.ConfigMap {
    configMap := &kafka.ConfigMap{}
    for key, value := range config {
        err := configMap.SetKey(key, value)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("An error %v occurred while setting %v: %v", err, key, value))
        }
    }
    return configMap
}    

func NewKafkaConsumer(channels []string, config map[string]interface{}, consumerMapping map[string]EventConsumer) *KafkaConsumer {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    consumer, err := kafka.NewConsumer(getKafkaConsumerConfigMap(config))
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("An error %v occurred while starting kafka consumer.", err)
    }
    err = consumer.SubscribeTopics(channels, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("An error %v occurred while subscribing to kafka topics %v.", err, channels)
    }
    return &KafkaConsumer{eventChannels: channels, done: done, wg: &wg, consumer: consumer, consumerMapping: consumerMapping}
}    

func (kc *KafkaConsumer) getEvent(eventData []byte) *eventService.Event {
    event := eventService.Event{}
    err := proto.Unmarshal(eventData, &event)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("An error %v occurred while un marshalling data from kafka.", err))
    }
    return &event
}    

func (kc *KafkaConsumer) Consume() {
    go func() {
        run := true
        for run == true {
            select {
            case sig := <-kc.done:
                log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Caught signal %v: terminating \n", sig))
                run = false
                return
            default:
            }
            e := <-kc.consumer.Events()
            switch event := e.(type) {
            case kafka.AssignedPartitions:
                _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%% %v\n", event)
                err := kc.consumer.Assign(event.Partitions)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("An error %v occurred while assigning partitions.", err))
                }
            case kafka.RevokedPartitions:
                _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%% %v\n", event)
                err := kc.consumer.Unassign()
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("An error %v occurred while unassigning partitions.", err))
                }
            case *kafka.Message:
                domainEvent := kc.getEvent(event.Value)
                kc.wg.Add(1)
                go func(event *eventService.Event) {
                    defer kc.wg.Done()
                    if eventConsumer := kc.consumerMapping[domainEvent.EntityType]; eventConsumer != nil {
                        eventConsumer(*domainEvent)
                    } else {
                        log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Event consumer not found for %v event type", domainEvent.EntityType))
                    }
                }(domainEvent)
            case kafka.PartitionEOF:
                fmt.Printf("%% Reached %v\n", e)
            case kafka.Error:
                _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%% Error: %v\n", e)
            }
        }
    }()
}    

func (kc *KafkaConsumer) Close() {
    log.Println("Waiting")
    kc.wg.Wait()
    kc.done <- true
    log.Println("Done waiting")
    err := kc.consumer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("An error %v occurred while closing kafka consumer.", err))
    }
}
```

And below is the main thread code

```
    package main    

import (
    "event-service/pkg/pb"
    "event-service/pkg/svc"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)    

func main() {
    eventConsumerMapping := map[string]svc.EventConsumer{"doctor-created": func(event eventService.Event) {
        log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Got event %v from kafka", event))
    }}
    consumerConfig := map[string]interface{}{
        "bootstrap.servers":               "localhost:9092",
        "group.id":                        "catalog",
        "go.events.channel.enable":        true,
        "go.application.rebalance.enable": true,
        "enable.partition.eof":            true,
        "auto.offset.reset":               "earliest",
    }
    kafkaConsumer := svc.NewKafkaConsumer([]string{"doctor-created"}, consumerConfig, eventConsumerMapping)
    kafkaConsumer.Consume()
    kafkaConsumer.Close()
}
```

The problem here is that the application is not ending at all sometimes and its not executing the `consume` function in some runs, what am i missing here ?

Comment: "Now this Consumer go routine is supposed to be shutdown when the application which is the main go routine shuts down." This is guaranteed to happen. When the `main` goroutine exits, the process exits, and all running goroutines stop.

Comment: @Adrian this is not happening

Comment: The reason it sometimes doesn't consume at all is that all `Consume` does is start a goroutine; `Close` then calls `Wait`; if `Consume` has not yet called `Add`, the `Wait` immediately returns and your program exits.

Comment: I guarantee it is. There is no scenario where `main` returns and the program continues to run.

Comment: Okay, assuming that there are messages in the queue, the consume goroutine is not reading those msgs, it just exits. Do you know why?

Comment: Your `Consume` routine can spawn other routines. That's when managing channels (buffers full or not, closed or not, waitgroups, ...) a bit tricky. Why not use `context.WithCancel(context.Background())` from the main func, pass that in, and when the main function returns, have a `defer cfunc()` in there, so all routines have a context cancellation to listen for and return

Comment: Also `e := <-kc.consumer.Events()` should be part of the `select-case` where you're listening for `<-kc.done`, if not `kc.consumer.Events()` could well be blocking (depending on the rest of your code).

Comment: I didn’t understand the context part @EliasVanOotegem can you please give an example

Comment: See my second comment as to why it sometimes doesn't read any messages.

Comment: Here's a [blog post](https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/2018-06-17-golang-using-context-cancellation/) with some examples. Contexts are awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here goes the solution, 
 1. Since the consumer go routine should live as long as the main go routine is alive and the main go routine is also an endless go routine, closing the consumer go routine while the go routine is running, isn't the correct approach.

So the following solution works

```
package main    

import (
    "event-service/pkg/pb"
    "event-service/pkg/svc"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sync"
)    

func main() {
    eventConsumerMapping := map[string]svc.EventConsumer{"doctor-created": func(event eventService.Event) {
        log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Got event %v from kafka", event))
    }}
    consumerConfig := map[string]interface{}{
        "bootstrap.servers":               "localhost:9092",
        "group.id":                        "catalog-2",
        "session.timeout.ms":              6000,
        "go.events.channel.enable":        true,
        "go.application.rebalance.enable": true,
        "enable.partition.eof":            true,
        "auto.offset.reset":               "earliest",
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    kafkaConsumer := svc.NewKafkaConsumer([]string{"doctor-created"}, consumerConfig, eventConsumerMapping)
    kafkaConsumer.Consume(&wg)
    wg.Wait()
    kafkaConsumer.Close()
}
```

The service definition

```
package svc    

import (
    "event-service/pkg/pb"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto"
    "gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1/kafka"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
)    

type EventConsumer func(event eventService.Event)    

type KafkaConsumer struct {
    done            chan bool
    consumer        *kafka.Consumer
    consumerMapping map[string]EventConsumer
    sigChan         chan os.Signal
    channels        []string
}    

func getKafkaConsumerConfigMap(config map[string]interface{}) *kafka.ConfigMap {
    configMap := &kafka.ConfigMap{}
    for key, value := range config {
        err := configMap.SetKey(key, value)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("An error %v occurred while setting %v: %v", err, key, value))
        }
    }
    return configMap
}    

func NewKafkaConsumer(channels []string, config map[string]interface{}, consumerMapping map[string]EventConsumer) *KafkaConsumer {
    sigChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    consumer, err := kafka.NewConsumer(getKafkaConsumerConfigMap(config))
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("An error %v occurred while starting kafka consumer.", err)
    }
    err = consumer.SubscribeTopics(channels, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("An error %v occurred while subscribing to kafka topics %v.", err, channels)
    }
    return &KafkaConsumer{channels: channels, sigChan: sigChan, done: done, consumer: consumer, consumerMapping: consumerMapping}
}    

func (kc *KafkaConsumer) getEvent(eventData []byte) *eventService.Event {
    event := eventService.Event{}
    err := proto.Unmarshal(eventData, &event)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("An error %v occurred while un marshalling data from kafka.", err))
    }
    return &event
}    

func (kc *KafkaConsumer) Consume(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    signal.Notify(kc.sigChan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        run := true
        defer wg.Done()
        for run == true {
            select {
            case sig := <-kc.sigChan:
                fmt.Printf("Caught signal %v: terminating\n", sig)
                run = false
            case ev := <-kc.consumer.Events():
                switch e := ev.(type) {
                case kafka.AssignedPartitions:
                    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%% %v\n", e)
                    _ = kc.consumer.Assign(e.Partitions)
                case kafka.RevokedPartitions:
                    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%% %v\n", e)
                    _ = kc.consumer.Unassign()
                case *kafka.Message:
                    domainEvent := kc.getEvent(e.Value)
                    wg.Add(1)
                    go func(event *eventService.Event) {
                        defer wg.Done()
                        if eventConsumer := kc.consumerMapping[domainEvent.EntityType]; eventConsumer != nil {
                            eventConsumer(*domainEvent)
                        } else {
                            log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Event consumer not found for %v event type", domainEvent.EntityType))
                        }
                    }(domainEvent)
                case kafka.PartitionEOF:
                    fmt.Printf("%% Reached %v\n", e)
                case kafka.Error:
                    // Errors should generally be considered as informational, the client will try to automatically recover
                    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%% Error: %v\n", e)
                }
            }
        }
    }()
}    

func (kc *KafkaConsumer) Close() {
    err := kc.consumer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("An error %v occurred while closing kafka consumer.", err))
    }
}
```